# how to clear local storage of react-native-webview?

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

how to clear **localStorage** of [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview) and

what is the best way to clear **localstorage** of webview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can use `injectedJavaScript` to clear localstorage. we can call this.clearLocalStorage(); to clear localStorage

```
clearLocalStorage = () => {
    this.setState({ isCookieClear: true }, () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ isCookieClear: false });
      }, 2000);
    });
  };
```

```
const {isCookieClear}=this.state;

let myInjectedJs = `(function(){
  ${isCookieClear?`window.localStorage.clear(); `:''}
})();`

return (
<WebView
 ref="webview"
 javaScriptEnabled={true}
 domStorageEnabled={true}
 injectedJavaScript={myInjectedJs}
 useWebKit={true}
 />
)
```